# Тесно связанная по смыслу со сказуемым придаточная часть и ее отделение запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую в таком предложении:"Она принимает тебя каким ты есть"?

Comment: Сначала нужно слово добавить: "Она принимает тебя **таким**, как**ой** ты есть."

Comment: Да, в таком случае постановка запятой не вызывает вопроса.Но нужно ли все же ставить запятую именно в первом варианте:"Она принимает тебя каким ты есть?".Например, если стоит задача записать услышанное слово в слово, не исказив при этом предложения?

Comment: А такое предложение грамматически корректно? Иначе нет смысла расставлять запятые в некорректном предложении.

Comment: Допустим, такое предложение возможно в разговорной речи или в речи неграмотного деревенского человека. Как в таком случае быть, если надо передать услышанное дословно?

Comment: Это зависит от отношения к говорящему. Можно (в его интересах и с его ведома) исправить, а можно (в интересах стенографической точности) в скобках указать, что это передано "дословно", отмежевавшись тем самым от особенностей речи персонажа.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: *Она принимает тебя **таким, какой** ты есть.*

Практически все пишут именно так.

Но вот примеры с пропуском местоимения:

(1) ―  Хочешь показать всей этой мрази, **какой ты есть**?.. [Николай Дежнев. Год бродячей собаки (2002)]

(2) На что Светочка как-то неопределенно махнула рукою, ничего, мол, уж я потерплю, или, наоборот, я не слушаю, говори, мол, что хочешь, или, может быть, я так люблю тебя, несмотря ни на что, ладно уж, оставайся **какой ты есть**. [Алексей Макушинский. Город в долине (2012)]

Но в предложении (1)  управление такое: показать (что?). Тогда это обычное  СПП.

В предложении (2) возможно такое понимание: **оставайся собой**, поэтому несоответствии в падеже (оставайся таким) не воспринимается на слух как однозначно  неправильное.
Запятая, как мы видим, **не ставится** в сочетании "оставайся какой ты Есть". Ударение падает на оборот, но не на глагол. Так обозначается **тесная связь со сказуемым.**

Но в других случаях это **несоответствие видится явно**, поэтому вариант без местоимения представляется **стилистически некорректным**.

Примечание

Если автор хочет дать **речевую характеристику** не слишком грамотного  персонажа, то это не очень удобный случай (его могут просто не понять).

Образованные люди тоже могут ошибаться, но в этом случае при записи их речи нужно ее **корректировать,** нет  даже смысла заострять на этом внимание.  Если же  возникнут вопросы, то следует объяснить **причину** редактирования.